# Replace Add to cart into Add to wishlist functionality woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

If we click on add to cart button it will appears in the cart function automatically same i want to do with wishlist. in fact if possible i want to change add to cart to wishlist only.
so if any one click on add to wishlist button it will not refresh full page and appears at the top corner at the cart place
please help me

Comment: So you want to change the text "Add to Cart" to "Add to Wishlist" and that's it?

Comment: @Howlin i think he wants what i want and thats to replace the add to cart function to wishlist so you are adding the item to a list rather a basket to checkout.

Comment: @Keelan, in that case you can set all the  prices to  0 and hide them and replace "Add to cart" to "Add to  Wishlist".

Comment: @Howlin What i did in the end was make default payment cash on delivery but change the wording. This way they still can checkout but there is no payment necessary.